Trouble updating/removing Brave
I'm new to Linux. I installed brave using the terminal few weeks ago. When I open it I get a message saying it can't update. I followed the instructions to update it but no matter what I do I get the same message. I then tried to remove it but no matter what I seem to do I get the same message:
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.
I've searched high and low and have tried everything I could find. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried to navigate these steps but I must be doing something wrong as none of the methods listed here worked:*
"Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source"*
The instructions I followed are from brave.com/linux and read as follows:
sudo apt install curl
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main"|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brave-browser

"I installed brave using the terminal few weeks ago." There are many ways to install "using the terminal." Please edit your question above to tell us EXACTLY how you did it. Review your shell history if you don't recall. Or show us the link to whatever instructions you followed.
